# Receiving 401 Unauthorized error in Sendgrid with Strapi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sendgrid, strapi

I'm trying to add a "forgot password" link in my application, using the built-in API provided by Strapi. I've included the configuration for Sendgrid in config/plugins.js:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    email: {
      provider: "sendgrid",
      providerOptions: {
        apiKey: env('SENDGRID_API_KEY'),
      },
      settings: {
        defaultFrom: "myemail@gmail.com",
        defaultReplyTo: "myemail@gmail.com",
      },
    },
  });
```

Every answer I find about this error is about adding the API key in the environment variables, which I've already done (and re-done) several times. I also re-created my API key twice, in case it expired, but it's still the same. I don't understand, it was working perfectly well a couple days ago but now I'm stuck on this error. Any idea what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Probably indeed the expression env('SENDGRID_API_KEY') is not resolving the correct api key. You can also directly put your api key in the json like this:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
email: {
  provider: "sendgrid",
  providerOptions: {
    apiKey: 'SG.MY_SENDGRID_API_KEY',// <== not using the env function
  },
  settings: {
    defaultFrom: "myemail@gmail.com",
    defaultReplyTo: "myemail@gmail.com",
  },
},
```

If this works, the plugin is working, and you can focus on why the env() function is not resolving the variable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).